# Add ManyToManyField relationship on save, and create objects if they not exist

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I want to 'attach' a manytomany relationship on form submit.

The example is the classic blog tags-post relation: a post can have multiple tags related

In django-admin it works, but i can't figure how to do in views...

my code:

```
def add_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.author = request.user
            newentry = model_instance.save()

            #some magic needed here, this will never works
            for tag in model_instance.tags.all():
                t = Tag.objects.get_or_create(author=request.user, title=tag.title, slug=slugify(tag.title))
                model_instance.tags.add(t)
            #end of magic

            return HttpResponseRedirect("/blog/")
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render_to_response(
        'blog/add_post.html',
        {'form' : form },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm using the [automatic tokenization from select2.js](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) in the template, so i can to add tags "on the fly", but i'm not sure how to handle it with django...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newentry = model_instance.save()
```

The `save()` method on a model instance will not return anything, unlike the same method on a form. You should reuse `model_instance` instead of using `newentry`.

I'd also take a look at `get_or_create()` to create the tag if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: +1 for `get_or_create()`, i didn't know about it :) but reusing `model_instance` i get `'instancemethod' object is not iterable` error

Comment: Ah, missed that: you need to add some parentheses after `all`: `for tag in model_instance.tags.all():`

Comment: nope, the post is created but no tag is attached... I'll edit the code above

Comment: `get_or_create` returns a `(obj, created)` tuple, not just a model instance. This is commonly solved with `t, _ = get_or_create()` to unpack the return value.

Comment: it doesn't work either... new tags are not added, nor existing ones... i'm not sure about the for loop on "not existing" items...

Answer (score 1):

I have a blog where I have a ManyToManyField between posts and projects, and I select the projects to create a relationship to in the post form.

When you use commit=False on form.save(), you need to use form.save_m2m() after the form is saved using post.save().

This is what part of my view function looks like:

```
 form = PostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    post = form.save(commit=False)
                    post.author = request.user
                    post.save()
                    # This saves the project relation
                    form.save_m2m()
```

For your usage, I would try moving the model_instance.save() and form.save_m2m() after your magic.

Another thing about get_or_create() is that it returns a tuple with the object that was gotten or created, and a boolean in regards to whether it created the object. So you need to only pass model_instance.tags.add() the created object.

```
form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
        model_instance.author = request.user

        #some magic needed here, this will never works
        for tag in model_instance.tags.all():
            t, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(author=request.user, title=tag.title, slug=slugify(tag.title))
            model_instance.tags.add(t)
        #end of magic

        model_instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
```

Comment: Could you post up your form here?   maybe try printing out t in the for loop to make sure that model_instance.tags.all() is what is holding the tags...

Answer (score 0):

As a database programmer (with a little django experience) I would argue that you should normalize your models.  IE, add a third table (call it something like Post Tags) and set it up as an intermediary between posts and tags.  So the relationship from Post to Post Tags would be 1:M and the relationship from Tags to Post Tags would be 1:M